# How to split a string with multiple conditions in python?

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement, split

Suppose I have a pandas series op= SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210)
I would like an output like this ["SU", "3180"] ["CMG", "3200"] ["SU", "3210"]

My code looks like this:

```
if op.str.contains('None').item():
    print('No Prereq for this course :) ')

else: 
    string = list()
    if op.str.contains('or').item():
        string=op.str.split('or')
    if op.str.contains('and').item():
        string=op.str.split('and')

    for item in string:
        print("Pre-req number:",item)
        for i in item:
            res=i.split()
            print(res)
```

The ouput I am getting is like this ['SU', '3180'] ['(CMG', '3200', 'or', 'SU', '3210)']

How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

[Regex](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html) can provide an easy solution

```
import re

txt = "op= SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210) "
```

create the pattern:

```
reg_exp  = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]{2,3})(\s+\d{4})")
```

find the matches:

```
re.findall(reg_exp, txt)
```

which returns:

> [('SU', ' 3180'), ('CMG', ' 3200'), ('SU', ' 3210')]

To build your regular expressions I would recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, split the string by you operators and brackets and extracts the operands like below

```py
import re

s = "SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210)"

tokens = re.split(r"and|or|\(|\)", s)

extracts = [token.strip().split() for token in tokens if len(token.strip())>0]
print(extracts)
```

**Output**

`[['SU', '3180'], ['CMG', '3200'], ['SU', '3210']]`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> a = 'CMG 3200 or SU 3210'
>>> parts = a.split('or')
>>> parts
['CMG 3200 ', ' SU 3210']
>>> broken_parts = [p.strip().split() for p in parts]
>>> broken_parts
[['CMG', '3200'], ['SU', '3210']]
```

Basically, you need just 2nd and 5th lines from the snippet I posted, the rest is there just for the display.

Answer (score 0):

`x =list(filter(lambda x:x, map(lambda x:re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', x), res)))`

`print (x)` 
This will remove the parenthesis from the output

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need a simple helper to get rid of "and", "or" and parentheses:

```
def replace_all(txt, old, new):
    for word in old:
        txt = txt.replace(word, new)
    return txt

r = replace_all(op, ["and", "or", "(", ")"], ",")   # 'SU 3180 , ,CMG 3200 , SU 3210,'
```

Then you can use `split` to get the desired result:

```
print([part.split() for part in r.split(",") if part.strip()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You might want to think about if it's important that the original string specified AND and OR, but your desired output does not reflect that information.

```
myString = 'SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210)' 
prereqs = list()

## Separating courses
arr1 = myString.split('or')
for i in arr1:
  for j in i.split('and'):
    ## cleaning
      j = j.replace('(', '')
      j = j.replace(')', '')
      j = j.strip()
      ## Split into letter/codes
      j= j.split(' ')
      prereqs.append(j)

print(prereqs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word="SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210) "
st1=word.replace("(","",-1)
st2=st1.replace(")","",-1)
st3=st2.replace("and",",",-1)
st4=st3.replace("or",",",-1)
lst1=list(st4.split(","))
res=[]
d=""
for i in lst1:
    j=i.strip()
    if d in j:
    res.append(j.split(" "))
print(res)
```

Try this!!!

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
([A-Z]+)\s+(\d+)
```

might simply work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fpgzpX/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"([A-Z]+)\s+(\d+)"
string = "SU 3180 and (CMG 3200 or SU 3210)"

print([list(i) for i in re.findall(expression, string)])
print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
[['SU', '3180'], ['CMG', '3200'], ['SU', '3210']]
[('SU', '3180'), ('CMG', '3200'), ('SU', '3210')]
```